MATLAB: Issue assigning variable size debugging
I need to fix the variable sizes of my code, but I am unable to fix it.
function [A, B] = genMat(n)
    % Initialize the n-by-n matrix A with zeros
    A = zeros(n, n);

    % Populate matrix A based on the hint
    for i = 1:n
        for j = 1:n
            if j == n
                A(i, j) = 1; % Last column is filled with 1s
            elseif i > 1
                A(i, j) = A(i - 1, j) + A(i - 1, j + 1);
            end
        end
    end

    % Initialize the n-by-n matrix B with zeros
    B = zeros(n, n);

    % Populate matrix B based on the description
    for i = 1:n
        for j = 1:n
            if j <= n
                B(i, j) = A(i, n - j + 1); % Flip A horizontally
            end
        end
    end
end


Tried with various variable sizing parameters, but still run into sizing issues of A and B.
Issues: Variable B must be of size [9 9]. It is currently of size [5 5]. Check where the variable is assigned a value, incorrect
Matrix B correct upon call: [A, B] = genMat(3)
Variable B must be of size [5 5]. It is currently of size [3 3]. Check where the variable is assigned a value, Matrix B correct upon call: [A, B] = genMat(7)
Variable B must be of size [13 13]. It is currently of size [7 7]. Check where the variable is assigned a value, incorrect
Matrix B correct upon call: [A, B] = genMat(n), for arbitrary n>1
Variable B must be of size [41 41]. It is currently of size [21 21]. Check where the variable is assigned a value.

Please show us the actual code you are using to call this routine, and what you expect to get as a result of this call.  Also, please post the assignment wording so we can deduce what is going wrong.

We need you to [edit] your question to include a [mcve] so we can reproduce the error. If I just run genMat(5) this works fine...

It would help if you described what your code is supposed to do. As of right now, we don't know what behavior is correct or incorrect.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
